# Babel sets wrong chapter, section, etc. language

Tags: babel

I do have a document basically in English, and sometimes
text in other language should be embedded
(i.e. change to Other, then change to English).
My attempt is to load both languages in the preamble, like this

```
\ifx\UseAlsoOther\undefined
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
\else
    \usepackage[Other,english]{babel}
\fi
\selectlanguage{english}
```

Basically it works, but chapter, section, etc. it outputted in the Other language if \UseAlsoOther is defined. What do I wrong?

Comment: Can you please provide a compilable document? This is a fragment only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can happen if you have english also a documentclass option. In this case you pass to babel the language "english,other,english" and then babel ignores the second english:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}

\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

This gives the warning

```
Package babel Warning: Last declared language option is `english',
(babel)                but the last processed one was `ngerman'.
(babel)                The main language cannot be set as both a global
(babel)                and a package option. Use `main=english' as
(babel)                option. Reported on input line 404.
```